# Remove entries from network drop down menu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

When I click the little wifi icon in the top right of my screen, I can see:

- 4 identical entries for "New Mobile Broadband (GSM) connection..."
- 2 identical entries for "iPhone Network"
- ashlee's iPhone network

These are in addition to the usual networks that I use. I have never connected to any of them, I don't know who Ashley is, and restarting my computer does not help.

The solution is not simply to rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ as this only lists networks I have previously connected to.

How do I remove these entries?

Here is photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvWqa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the entries from the bluetooth device lists.